# Long title without suitable wrap point causes layout issue on Stack Exchange mobile website

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-safari

I was using the Stack Exchange mobile website today and came across a title that messed up the layout a bit. Not sure whether this has been noted to the admins already.

See screenshot of the issue:

[image: title issue]

As can be seen, this is probably caused by the `inline code` environment in combination with a long string containing no spaces that is longer than allowed.

Comment: Indeed, this was already reported.